# sicp pattern matching - compound?

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I am watching the video lectures of SICP. Currently I am on 4A Pattern Matching and Rule Based Substitution.

So far, I found the Matcher and the Instantiator is easy. But I can't get my head into The simplifier.

```
(define (simplifier the-rules)
  (define (simplify-exp exp)
    (try-rules (if (compound? exp)
                   (map simplify-exp exp)
                   exp)))
  (define (try-rules exp)
    (define (scan rules)
      (if (null? rules)
          exp
          (let ((dict (match (pattern (car rules))
                        exp
                        (empty-dictionary))))
            (if (eq? dict 'failed)
                (scan (cdr rules))
                (simplify-exp (instantiate (skeleton (car rules)) dict))))))
    (scan the-rules))
  simplify-exp)
```

I saw another question here on this topic which defined `compound?` in terms of `pair?`. But, Then what `simplify-exp` feeding to `try-rules`?

Comment: Are you using racket or scheme? The question is tagged with [tag:scheme], but your code starts with `#lang racket`.  They're *similar* languages, but they're not the same. In Scheme, and many Lisps, the empty list *is* an atom, so `((null? s) '())` (what you added in the answer) is redundant after `((atom ?s) s)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. The rules are going to apply in every node as promised. You can vote to delete the question. But, I would add some explanation on how I made it working.

I changed some code. The original code seems written with some other semantic in mind. I added some commentary where I made some decision on my own.

```
#lang racket
;matcher
(define (match pat exp dict)
  (cond ((eq? dict 'failed) 'failed)
        ;matched
        ((and (null? pat) (null? exp)) dict)
        ;so far matched, but no more
        ((or (null? pat) (null? exp)) 'failed)
        ((atom? pat)
         (if (atom? exp)
             (if (eq? pat exp)
                 dict
                 'failed)
             'failed))
        ((pat-const? pat)
         (if (constant? exp)
             (extend-dict pat exp dict)
             'failed))
        ((pat-variable? pat)
         (if (variable? exp)
             (extend-dict pat exp dict)
             'failed))
        ((pat-exp? pat)
             (extend-dict pat exp dict))
        ((atom? exp) 'failed)
        (else
         (match (cdr pat)
                (cdr exp)
                (match (car pat) (car exp) dict)))))
(define (pat-const? pat)
  (eq? (car pat) '?c))
(define (pat-variable? pat)
  (eq? (car pat) '?v))
(define (pat-exp? pat)
  (eq? (car pat) '?))
(define constant? number?)
(define variable? symbol?)
;instantiator
(define (instantiate skeleton dict)
  (define (loop s)
    (cond ((atom? s) s)
          ;we cant run past the nil line
          ((null? s) '())
          ((skeleton-evaluation? s) (evaluate s dict))
          (else
           (cons (loop (car s)) (loop (cdr s))))))
  (loop skeleton))

(define (skeleton-evaluation? s)
  (eq? (car s) ':))
;made it simpler, no environment constant, sorry
(define (evaluate s dict)
  (let ((data (lookup (cadr s) dict)))
    (if (null? data)
        (display "error in rules. mismatch")
        (cadr data))))
;simplifier
(define (simplifier rules)
  (define (simplify-exp exp)
    (try-rules (if (list? exp)
                   (map simplify-exp exp)
                   exp)))
  (define (try-rules exp)
    (define (scan rule)
      (if (null? rule)
          exp
          (let ((dict (match (pattern (car rule)) exp (empty-dict))))
              (if (eq? dict 'failed)
                  (scan (cdr rule))
                  (simplify-exp (instantiate (skeleton (car rule)) dict))))))
    (scan rules))
  simplify-exp)

(define pattern car)
(define skeleton cadr)

;dictionary
(define (empty-dict)
  '())
(define (extend-dict pat exp dict)
  (let ((v (lookup (cadr pat) dict)))
    (if (null? v)
        (cons (list (cadr pat) exp) dict)
        (if (eq? (cadr v) exp)
            dict
            'failed))))
(define (lookup s dict)
  (cond ((null? dict) '())
        ((eq? (caar dict) s) (car dict))
        (else (lookup s (cdr dict)))))


;extend racket
(define (atom? a)
  (and (not (null? a)) (not (pair? a))))
```

And? you know what? It works `:)`

Comment: Are you using racket or scheme?  In Scheme, and many Lisps, the empty list *is* an atom, so `((null? s) '())` is redundant after `((atom ?s) s)`.  The question is tagged with [tag:scheme], but your code starts with `#lang racket`.  They're *similar* languages, but they're not the same.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, I am using DrRacket. The mit-scheme does not feel well to me. Thanks for your comment. that make everything clear. In fact I defined the `atom?`, but I thought `'()` shouldn't be an atom.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Racket is a scheme per the tag-wiki. It's also a Lisp.

Comment: @benrudgers Racket is a language with many similarities to, and descended from Scheme, but not everything that's true of Scheme is true of Racket.  And there are differences in different Lisps, too. E.g., in many traditional Lisps, including Common Lisp, the empty list is the same as the symbol NIL, and is the false value.  In Scheme, only the actual boolean value #f is false.  OP mentioned that "The original code seems written with some other semantic in mind," and one of the changes made to the code is the addition of `(atom? s)` in a `cond` before a `(null? s)`.  In many Lisps, …

Comment: @benrudgers … (possibly including Racket and Scheme;  I'm not sure whether all of OP's changes were actually necessary) the `(null? s)` would be redundant since the empty list *is* an atom.  There seems to be a trend of people (possibly due to instructors) saying that they're using Scheme, but actually using Racket.  Lots of code will work in both places, but not all code.  E.g., Racket uses immutable cons-cells by default now, so in Scheme in you can `(set-car! (cons a b) c)`, but in Racket you can't.  I don't think that asking *what programming language OP is actually using* is unreasonable…

Comment: @benrudgers …when the tags suggest one language, but the actual code that's been posted indicate that a different language is actually being used, no matter how similar the languages might be.  The comment got two upvotes, so it seems that at least two other users agree, too. :)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I understand your point. Solely within the context of StackOverflow, I disagree because I believe that the [scheme] and [racket] tags are working and because I do not see an alternative that I believe would work better. By "working better" I am again referring to the context of StackOverflow and therefore "better" means creating information useful for solving immediate programming problems *and* making that information easy to find. People search for "scheme" when using Racket's languages be it BSL, ISL, or `#lang racket`.  meta.stackoverflow.com is for discussing tag philosophy.

Comment: @benrudgers I don't think there's anything necessarily wrong with the tags, either.  I just think that if someone's writing in Racket or Scheme, they should be aware of which they're using and to state it, *especially* if they're up against something that may be a result of the difference between them.